# jquery .text validation fail

Tags: jquery, html, validation, whitespace

I found this issue to always happen and not consistent.

This issue causing jquery .text comparison not working, because jQuery trying to compare actual wording but fail.

Eg: 'Second Title' is showing as 1 line of wording at browser, but when view html source, the 'Second' and 'Title' is in different line.

Thus, causing `if($(this).text()=="Second Title")` not working.

Any good way to eliminate the whitespaces at html source in such case? so that I can continue to use .text comparison.

Sample showing not working version.

```
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">

          <tr>
            <td width="400" colspan="3" align="center"><span>First Title</span></td>
          </tr>

          <tr align="center">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="400" colspan="3" align="center"><span>Second
              Title</span></td>
          </tr>

          <tr align="center">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
          </tr>

    </table>




$(document).ready(function() {

    replaceText();

});


function replaceText()
{

    var first, second
    first= "", second="";

    $("*").each(function() {
        if($(this).children().length==0)
        {
            if($(this).text()=="First Title")
            {                
                first+= jQuery.trim($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("td").eq(0).text());
            }

            if($(this).text()=="Second Title")
            {                
                second+= jQuery.trim($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("td").eq(0).text());                   
            }                                     
        }
    });    


alert(first);
alert(second); //fail

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't rely on repetitions of whitespace (say, 3 spaces), you could replace all contiguous whitespace by a space.

```
function shrinkWhitespace(t) {
    return t.replace(/\s+/g, ' '); 
}
```

Example

```
>> shrinkWhitespace('Second \n\tTitle') == 'Second Title'
true
```